# Encoding Categorical data with large Data set

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, encoding, categorical-data

I have a large data set with 156000 rows and 37 columns. The columns represents an insurance attributes. We can divide the attribute in three type: numeric, categorical and alphanumeric. This attribute is an input value for Neural network but the NNT accept only numeric data. I must encoding the categorical and alphanumeric value. For the categorical attribute that contain a few different value I use one-hot method: one column for category, with a 1 or 0 in each cell for if the row contained that column's category.

Instead, for category attributes that contain many different values, so as not to increase the number of columns too much, use the following command:

```
df["ATT1"] = df["ATT1"].astype('category')
df["ATT2"] = df["ATT2"].astype('category')
df["ATT1"] = df["ATT1"].cat.codes
df["ATT2"] = df["ATT2"].cat.codes
```

Transform an object attribute to category attribute and for each category a I associate an integer value.
When I launch the  model by TensorFlow the function loss remain to 0 for each iteration and accuracy remains constant at 1.

I think this is because I'm wrong to encode categorical attributes. The model is built in the correct way, when I turning it in with another data base the loss function, accuracy and output are corrects. There is an encoding method for categorical data that contain a lot of different value?

Comment: @jigasse: You can try embedding method. You can have a look at wide-n-deep method in TF.

Comment: For your task gradient boosting with categorical features support might work well. Check out CatBoost https://catboost.yandex
If you do so, do not use one-hot encoding as preprocessing phase, it'll affect both accuracy and speed of the training.